# Running multiple instance of EA in parallel

Tags: enterprise-architect

We are creating around 1000 class elements in EA through addin. Now instead of creating all the 1000 elements in the single repository, we want to create multiple instances of the repository in parallel, and divide the creation of 1000 elements within the multiple instances of repository and finally merge all the instances to single repository in EA. Is this possible in the EA through addin?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. Element creation is atomar and can be run in parallel. However, I doubt this will increase performance in any way. Each element creation goes through the central repository and that will be the bottle neck.

Comment: can we create the multiple eap files through addin and add the elements to different eap files and then finally merge all the eap's to single eap file

Comment: Sure. But the final merge would be the same bottleneck.